# AWS DynamoDB Scan output

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS JS SDK for dynamo, and running a scan to get a list of the items in a table.  The results come back but each value is nested inside a key of the attribute type:

For example:

I would expect
image: { thumbnail: 'http://foobar.jpg' }

But I am getting
image: { thumbnail: { S: 'http://foobar.jpg' } }

Is there a way to get the SDK to spit out plain values?

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you're currently using to run the scan?

Comment: var params = {
            TableName: TABLE_NAME,
        }

        dynamodb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack) }
            callback(data)
        })

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler
No more having to tedious keying

Answer (score 0):

Don't scan with DynamoDb directly, use DynamoDb.DocumentClient() which simplifies the result set and pulls out the field type identifier.